# Ayuda con consulta sql para obtener el total de las ventas por mes

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, mariadb

Mi tabla venta tiene estos campos:

```
id 
usuario_id 
cliente_id 
fecha
subtotal
descuento
total
```

el campo fecha tipo `DATETIME`, y el campo total es  decimal(8,2) aunque eso no importa mucho, quisiera saber como hago mi consulta sql para que me salga asi:

```
Mes   /   Total
Enero    4200
Febrero  3500
Marzo     5200
y asi hasta diciembre
```

o...

```
ENERO FEBRERO MARZO
4200           3500           5200
```

Hasta ahora solo tengo que si pongo

```
SELECT SUM(v.total) AS "enero"  
FROM venta v
WHERE fecha BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-01-31'
```

me da el total de ventas en enero asi:

```
Enero
4200
```

Pero no se como hacer para que me arroje el de todos los meses, como agrupo esas consultas? ayuda porfa no soy muy bueno en SQL

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Prueba de este modo

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(v.fecha) AS Mes,
       SUM(v.total) AS Total
FROM venta v
WHERE YEAR(v.fecha) = '2019'
GROUP BY Mes
ORDER BY Mes ASC;
```

- Obtienes el nombre del mes con la función `MONTHNAME()` y le asignas un alias
- Como usaste una función de agregación `SUM()` entonces deberás agrupar los resultados, en este caso por la columna calculada `Mes`
- Opcionalmente puedes ordenar los resultados con `ORDER BY columnaNombre ASC`

Para poder pasar los meses de inglés a español, como te dejé en los comentarios; deberás consultar [esta liga de mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/locale-support.html) donde indica que al inicio ejecutes

```
SET lc_time_names = 'es_ES';
```

Comment: Perfecto me funciona bien, pero me da los meses en ingles, alguna forma de como pasarlos a español ? o eso ya lo hago yo en el backend con php por medio de IF?

Comment: me parece se puede cambiar dentro del contexto del alcance de MySQL por medio de https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/locale-support.html solo deberás añadir algo como esto al inicio `SET lc_time_names = 'es_ES';` de todos modos conviene cheques el enlace que te comparto, saludos @JoséAlexisCruzSolar

Comment: oye me estoy dando cuenta de que los agrupa por mes, y eso esta bien pero quiero que no tome de otros años, solo el actual, me explico? los meses de enero a diciembre del año actual porque creo que asi como esta sumara tambien si en 2018 vendi en el mes de enero, se lo sumara no?

Comment: revisa si la actualización que hice te sirve @JoséAlexisCruzSolar simplemente agregué un `WHERE` para comparar el año con uno en específico, en este caso el 2019

Comment: jajaja lo combinecon lo que tenia y quedo asi:

SELECT MONTHNAME(v.fecha) AS Mes,
       SUM(v.total) AS Total
FROM venta v 
WHERE fecha BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-12-31' GROUP BY Mes ORDER BY v.fecha ;

y ya me da solo del año en curso xD genial, gracias, ahora revisare lo de pasar los meses a español

Comment: ohhhhh tu solucion es mejor, gracias, marcare esta, eres respuesta como la mejor, eres muy bueno

Comment: Funciono lo de pasarlo a español, gracias :3

Comment: Men alguna idea para emplear lo mismo pero aplicado a los dias de la semana actual ?

Comment: claro, tienes 2 opciones investigar sobre `NAMEDAY()` o abrir otra pregunta para ayudarte @JoséAlexisCruzSolar

Comment: Pues al final lo he hecho asi:

SELECT DAYNAME(v.fecha) AS Dia,
        SUM(v.total) AS Total
        FROM venta v 
        WHERE v.fecha BETWEEN '2019-04-08' AND '2019-04-14'
        GROUP BY Dia ORDER BY v.fecha ;

pero saco las fechas del between lo saco con php, no se si hay alguna forma de sacarlo con SQL, sabes hacer eso? para que escriba abra una nueva pregunta xD

Answer (score 5):

Si quieres mostrar un resultado horizontal, con cada mes como columna, puedes hacer la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT
    SUM(IF(MONTH(fecha) = 1,  total, 0)) AS Ene,
    SUM(IF(MONTH(fecha) = 2,  total, 0)) AS Feb,
    SUM(IF(MONTH(fecha) = 3,  total, 0)) AS Mar,
    SUM(IF(MONTH(fecha) = 4,  total, 0)) AS Abr,
    SUM(IF(MONTH(fecha) = 5,  total, 0)) AS May,
    SUM(IF(MONTH(fecha) = 6,  total, 0)) AS Jun,
    SUM(IF(MONTH(fecha) = 7,  total, 0)) AS Jul,
    SUM(IF(MONTH(fecha) = 8,  total, 0)) AS Ago,
    SUM(IF(MONTH(fecha) = 9,  total, 0)) AS Sep,
    SUM(IF(MONTH(fecha) = 10, total, 0)) AS Oct,
    SUM(IF(MONTH(fecha) = 11, total, 0)) AS Nov,
    SUM(IF(MONTH(fecha) = 12, total, 0)) AS Dic
FROM venta
WHERE fecha BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-01-31';
```

Lo que hace la consulta es, en cada fila buscar el valor numérico del mes correspondiente a `fecha` y según el caso, sumando para esa eventual columna el valor que tenga `total` en la fila.

El resultado sería algo así, donde `X` sería el total para cada mes:

```
Ene  |  Feb  |  Mar  |  Abr  |  May  |  Jun  |  Jul  |  Ago  |  Sep  |  Oct  |  Nov  |  Dic
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 X   |   X   |   X   |   X   |   X   |   X   |   X   |   X   |   X   |   X   |   X   |   X
```

Comment: Genial!!!!!!!!! solo se te fue en el BETWEEN que era hasta el 31 del mes 12 xD pero lo cambie y funciono perfecto GRACIAS!!!!

Comment: Ohhh, yo tomé el `BETWEEN` que aparecía en la pregunta @JoséAlexisCruzSolar. Considera marcar como solución la respuesta que más se acerque a la solución de tu problema. Saludos.

Comment: Pues ambas son muy buenas respuestas pero me es mas util te forma vertical como me lo dio el otro chico, solo que me imprime los meses en ingles xD sabes alguna forma de pasarlo a español? o ya tocaria hacerlo desde el backend por medio de if?

Comment: @JoséAlexisCruzSolar la cuestión es marcar la respuesta que más te haya ayudado a resolver el problema, en este caso, deberías entonces marcar la respuesta de alfa p. En cuanto a los meses en español, puedes ejecutar esto previo a la consulta: `SET lc_time_names = 'es_ES';`, así te mostrará los meses en español.